# Mail to client asking the way he want to be shared with the document

Tags: word-choice

Have to ask the client about sharing the document in mail like "tell me How to share the document?" Want to know the perfect phrase that suits this .

Answer (score 2):

**Channel** -- [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/channel)

> (Noun) a means of communication or expression: such as (1) :  a path along which information (as data or music) in the form of an electrical signal passes (2) channels plural :  a fixed or official course of communication

**Example**: Please advise through which channel would you like me to share the XYZ files with you?